# Testing which element has focus when one lost it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is to test when an element (a SELECT) loses its focus if the focus has been transfered to another specific element (another SELECT). I want to trigger something when the focus is lost and is not on one of the two.

The problem is I test in the first select when it has lost the focus (with the blur event) if the other select has it, but the DOM is not yet updated.

Here's an exemple of what I did:

```
$select1.on("blur", function() {
    if($select2.is(":focus"))
    {
         // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

$select1 and $select2 are just two variables that contain the element. I read that JQuery adds an identifier ":focus" when an element gains the focus, but the way I did it, it doesn't work.

In all cases, it goes into the else "do something else".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt is right about the order of events but you can be a little more creative.

For example use a setTimeout to delay the check for blur so you know you already fired your focus. Simple.

```
$select1.on("blur", function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if($select2.is(":focus"))
    {
       // do something
    }
    else
    {
      // do something else
    }
  },100);
});
```

Try that one.

Comment: I hang my head in shame that I didn't consider this solution... :P

Comment: @Matt well its a bit of a hack but JavaScript tends to be a little hacky because of the low entry point and browser quirk history.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `blur` event is **distinctly** fired before the `focus` of the new element is, the *only* thing you can do is set a variable in one event and detect it in the other.

```
$select1.on('blur', function (e) {
    var $that = $(this);

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (($that.data('focussed') || 0) > e.timeStamp - 5) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
    }, 1);
}); 

$select2.on('focus', function (e) {
    $select1.data('focussed', e.timeStamp);
});
```

See it working here; http://jsfiddle.net/uZAMm/

Comment: How can I execute an action only if $select2 has not gain focus? I can't test it in $select2.focus because he might not gain it.

Comment: @maniak: the code is there. Add code to `// Do something` that you want executed if the focus is transferred, and add code to `// Something else` that you want to be executed if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, but can I achieve the same using a functionName.call(this) ? Because I found it sloppy to use setTimeout (I might be wrong to do so =D).

Comment: @maniak: when I said it was the ***only*** thing you can do, I wasn't exaggerating ;).

Comment: @maniak: Make sure you do it \@kitgui.com's way... it's far simpler than whatever I was trying to do.